# Trace of positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace, positive-semidefinite

Let $A =X +B$ with $X= (X_1+X_2) $all three semidefinite positive and B definite positive.  How can i proove that $$ trace A^{-1}X \leq trace( (X_1+ B)^{-1}X_1  +(X_2 +B)^{-1}X_2)$$

Comment: When everything is a scalar, your problem is proving $$\frac{X_1+X_2}{X_1+X_2+B}=\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+B}+\frac{X_2}{X_1+X_2+B}\leq \frac{X_1}{X_1+B}+\frac{X_2}{X_2+B}$$ for $X_1,X_2\geq 0$ and $B>0$. This is obviously true. I don't think you need the condition about the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A \ge X_i+B$, we have $A^{-1} \le (X_i+B)^{-1}$ and in turn $X_i^{1/2}A^{-1}X_i^{1/2} \le X_i^{1/2}(X_i+B)^{-1}X_i^{1/2}$. Thus $\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}X_i) \le \operatorname{tr}\left((X_i+B)^{-1}X_i\right)$. Sum up each side for $i=1,2$, the result follows.

Comment: Why is i that multiplying by the square root of a matrix by both sides preserve positive semidefinitness?

Comment: @Manuel Consider Sylvester's law of inertia. Alternatively, Let their difference be $D$ and consider $v^\ast Dv$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M_1=A^{-1}X_1$, $N_1=(X_1+B)^{-1}X_1$, and $Q_1=(X_1+B)^{-1}-A^{-1}$. Because $A-(X_1+B)=X_2$ is positive semidefinite, so is $Q_1$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Tr}(N_1-M_1)=\operatorname{Tr}\Big[Q_1X_1\Big]=\operatorname{Tr}\Big[Q_1^{1/2}Q_1^{1/2}X_1\Big]=\operatorname{Tr}\Big[Q_1^{1/2}X_1Q_1^{1/2}\Big]\geq0.
\end{align*}
Then, you can do the same with $M_2=A^{-1}X_2$, $N_2=(X_2+B)^{-1}X_2$, and $Q_2=(X_2+B)^{-1}-A^{-1}$.

Comment: @yurnerno Which propertie says that $Tr ( Q_1^{1/2}X_1Q_1^{1/2} ) \geq 0$. I can figure out $Tr(QX) \geq 0$ because $ Tr(LL^tT^tT) = Tr(L^tT^t T L) \geq 0$ being the last one positive semidefinite.

Comment: @Manuel See if you can be convinced that $Q_1^{1/2}X_1Q_1^{1/2}$ is positive semidefinite.